# Script function could not be found even though script works in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I just started learning about Google Apps Scripts and I created this script that will help me copy a range of data in Google Sheets into another sheet.

This is my code

```
function copyPaste() 
{
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1btVcMHU2a4hyU6gz3D4ZN7RYXX_HYWLKJPxuGmdKvEI').getSheetByName('Form1'); 
  const nutriSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1btVcMHU2a4hyU6gz3D4ZN7RYXX_HYWLKJPxuGmdKvEI').getSheetByName('Data');
  const nutriLastRow = nutriSheet.getLastRow(); 

  let copyRange = ss.getSheetValues(3,7,1,30); 
  let rowValues = ss.getRange(3,7,1,30).getValues();

  nutriSheet.getRange(nutriLastRow+1, 2, 1, 30).setValues(rowValues);
}
```

The code works when I run it from the app but when I tried to assign the script to a button(drawing) and entering copyPaste, it says "Script function copyPaste could not be found".

I made sure to name it as the function and not the google app script project name.

I ahve also tried opening it in incognito but it still didn't work.

I was really happy to get the code to work but now I need to figure out how to run it from Google Sheet.

I have also tried to use the ui.createMenu('Custom Menu') but I can't seem to get it to work. It says "Cannot call SpreadsheetApp.getUi() from this context"

```
function onOpen(e) {
  let ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); 
  ui.createMenu('Shortcusts')
    .addItem('Copy to Data', 'copyPaste')
    .addToUi(); 
};
```

I created this code by editting existing code on GitHub and modified it to fit my purpose.

Hope someone can help me with this, thanks in advance!

Comment: The onOpen runs when you open the sheet, refresh you're spreadsheet browser tab an see if the `Shortcusts` menu appears

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
function funko() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh1 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  const sh2 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const lr2 = sh2.getLastRow();
  let rowValues = sh1.getRange(3, 7, 1, 30).getValues();
  sh2.getRange(lr2 + 1, 2, 1, 30).setValues(rowValues);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After fiddling for a while, I found out that you had to open Google Apps Script from the spreadsheet or it won't work. Open spreadsheet > Extensions > Apps Script.

What I did wrong was that I opened Apps Script from Google Drive which caused my functions to be undetected.

The code worked fine and was able to link to a button.

Thanks